# NetBeans does not show functions list defined in the currently opened php file

Tags: php, netbeans

I've been trying NetBeans since morning. It's one heck of an IDE, but it beats the heck out of me to figure out how to enable the function list view for the file that I opened. For example, I got a library file that's got 100 functions in it. It's stupid that I need to use search to go a specific function.

I'm sure there is a way to get this done, but cannot figure it out. [netbeans.org](http://netbeans.org) does not have any info on this neither. Their help file does not do a good job in this regard either.

Netbeaners, out there! Give me a help pls.

Comment: It's called [Navigator](http://ui.netbeans.org/docs/ui/code_navigator/Navigator%20spec.html). Opened by Ctrl+7.

Comment: @zafarkhaja you should post this as an answer may be. I had this question, came to this link, saw there was no answer and was about close it when I saw the comments.

Comment: @roopunk, perhaps You're right. At first I thought it was too short for an answer.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

It's called [Navigator‌](http://ui.netbeans.org/docs/ui/code_navigator/Navigator%20spec.html)​. Opened by <kbd>Ctrl+7</kbd> or `Top Menu`->`Window`->`Navigator` (<kbd>Alt+w</kbd>, then <kbd>n</kbd>).

Comment: If Navigator isn't displaying your functions, make sure that your file's extension is mapped
 (Tools> Options> Miscellaneous> Files> File Associations).

For example, the extension for my Drupal .module files needed to be added with the MIME type `text/x-php5`, and then NetBeans needed a restart, before the Navigator displayed anything.

Comment: Definitely a time Saving feature

Comment: Is there also a way to open the navigator over the tabs?

Comment: @EdwardBlack you mean if it's possible to place the Navigator above the tabs? Sure, just drag it to the desired area.

Comment: No i mean if opening the navigator is also possible without using the shortcut, or is this the only way?

Comment: @EdwardBlack you can open it from the top menu: Window -> Navigator

Comment: thanks.Can you share if you have any list of short key for other useful things in net beans.Like i need to open project window.

Comment: @rahulsingh here you go https://netbeans.org/project_downloads/usersguide/shortcuts-80.pdf